# Parsed SimpleXMLElement is missing attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this small chunk of XML that I wish to parse in PHP. The `Works` tag is ok, I can parse all the attributes just fine. The problem I'm having is with the `Doesnt` tag, it seems that because it has text content that I can't access the attributes.

```
<Export id="123" apples="pears">
    <Works foo="bar" id="234"/>
    <Doesnt bar="foo" id="345">Stack Exchange</Doesnt>
</Export>
```

I run the following (very simple) code:

```
$plain = '<Export id="123" apples="pear....esnt></Export>'; // as above
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($plain);
$json = json_encode($sxe);
$native = json_decode($json);
print_r($sxe, true);
print_r($native, true);
```

And I end up with the following output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [apples] => pears
        )
    [Works] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => bar
                    [id] => 234
                )
        )
    [Doesnt] => Stack Exchange
)

stdClass Object
(
    [@attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 123
            [apples] => pears
        )

    [Works] => stdClass Object
        (
            [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [foo] => bar
                    [id] => 234
                )

        )

    [Doesnt] => Stack Exchange
)
```

As you can see, the `SimpleXMLElement` object and the `stdClass` object are both missing all the attributes for the `<Doesnt>` tag. **Is there some work around or alternative means to get at them?**

Comment: never trust `var_dump` or `print_r` output of an SimpleXml Element. Try to access the attributes and you will see they are there.

Comment: Aha! I cut down my example to keep it simple, I'll add my next step back in (i.e. json_encode)

Comment: Hi, to those who want to close this, I assure it is a real question with valid reusable knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

As @Gordon said, you don't get the whole picture with `print_r` and `var_dump`: `SimpleXMLElement Object` has some unusual properties, so these dumping functions would fail to represent its structure correctly.

Still, if you had used this instead:

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($plain);
var_dump($sxe->Doesnt);
```

... you would have seen these attributes and their values intact.

But look closely at the output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=2)
      'bar' => string 'foo' (length=3)
      'id' => string '345' (length=3)
  string 'Stack Exchange' (length=14)
```

It's kinda unusual, don't you think, to have `string` value just hanging up there - without any corresponding property owning it? But that's exactly what would make direct conversion problematic. JSON (as it is) deals with simple structures - objects and arrays - and this structure cannot be represented correctly in neither of them: you have at least to introduce some additional attribute to store the text content.

Still, this approach seems to be in demand (to some extent), and you're definitely not alone: here's an *open* [ticket](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54632) in PHP bug tracking system.

Comment: My actual use case is to use json_encode() with the `SimpleXMLElement`, which suffers from the same problem.

Comment: @Matt So it's XY problem here... if you had mentioned that in the original question, it probably wouldn't have been closed. Anyway, I can refer you to [this ticket](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54632) which describes both the roots of the problem and its possible solution. If you wish, I can update my answer with this info as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "XY" problem is but yeah, I've now updated the question to be clear at the top about what it is I'm asking. Is there any way to get it reopened? I think it's a totally valid question.

Comment: @Matt [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). As for reopening, I already gave my vote for it - but, frankly speaking, I've seen these questions ("How to convert XML to JSON in PHP") before, so this attempt won't probably succeed either.

Comment: Aha, yes, my first question definitely suffered from the XY problem, thanks for the heads up. This isn't a problem I've seen addressed here, I've looked! That ticket is reassuring though, at least it's not just me.